# IndexError: string index out of range Show in odoo-14.0

Tags: python

```
elif token[1] == 'in' and not (isinstance(token[2], Query) or token[2]):
```

Exception
IndexError: string index out of range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a Odoo error it's simply a Python error.

Your variable `token` is a string but by looking at your code `token` must be a list or tuple.

Answer (score 4):

This usually happens when we forget to wrap our search parameters into a tuple inside the list, like so:
`self.search(['field', '=', value])`

While it should be:
`self.search([('field', '=', value)])`
Note the **(** before `'field'`, and the **)** after `value`.